# Cannonball flight coordinate tracking

Tags: java, arraylist, point

So I just started working with `ArrayList` and `awt.Point`. What I am trying to accomplish here is to output an array of X and Y coordinates as the cannonball is in flight. However, when I run the program, I get a bunch of `Point[x=0,y=0]` within the array.

I think part of the problem maybe in return `Point`. I return a `Point` in `bowling.Move()` and `bowling.getLocation()`. It is possible that one is overriding the other? I feel that I am close to my result, but at a lose on how to get there.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cannonball {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Part 1: Open Scanner
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Part 2: Create a new cannonball
    Ball bowling = new Ball(0);

    //Part 3: Ask user for initial angle and starting velocity
    System.out.println("Alright, give us the angle at which to fire: ");
    bowling.setAngle(keyboard.nextDouble());
    System.out.println("And what is the initial velocity: ");
    bowling.setVel(keyboard.nextDouble());

    //Part 4: Return the points of the cannonball's flight
    for(int i=0; i<bowling.shoot.size(); i++) System.out.println(bowling.shoot);

    //Part x: Close input
    keyboard.close();
}

}

class Ball{
private double xPos, yPos, deltaSec;
private double alpha, v;
private double yVel, xVel;
private static final double gravity = -9.81;

public Ball(double xPos){
    this.xPos=xPos;
    yPos=0;
}

public Point move(double deltaSec){
    xPos += xVel*deltaSec;
    yPos += yPos*deltaSec;
    return new Point();
}

public void yVel(){
    yVel=v*Math.sin(alpha)*(deltaSec*gravity);
}

public void xVel(){
    xVel=v*Math.cos(alpha);
}

public Point getLocation(double xPos, double yPos){
    return new Point();
}

public void setAngle(double aplha){
    this.alpha=alpha;
}

public void setVel(double v){
    this.v=v;
}

public ArrayList<Point> shoot = new ArrayList<Point>();
{
    while(deltaSec<60){
        move(deltaSec);
        shoot.add(getLocation(xPos, yPos));
        deltaSec++;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a `Point` that represents the x and y coordinates at that timestamp, you should pass them to the point. `Point()` will create a point with coordinates 0/0.

You should either call the `Point(x,y)` constructor (which uses integer screen coordinates - intended to represent pixels!) or use `Point2D` resp. `Point2D.Double( x, y)`.

**Update:**

Here's an example implementation of what I guess is intended for `getLocation`:

```
//Point version
public Point getLocation(double xPos, double yPos){
   return new Point((int)xPos, (int)yPos); //Point only takes int coordinates
}

//Point2D version
public Point2D getLocation(double xPos, double yPos){
   return new Point2D.Double( xPos, yPos );
}
```

`move` should do the same, if it needs to return a point at all.

**UPDATE 2:**

You seem to have added this code:

```
public ArrayList<Point> shoot = new ArrayList<Point>();
//I add this line to highlight the difference: the line above is no method signature
{
  while(deltaSec<60){
    move(deltaSec);
    shoot.add(getLocation(xPos, yPos));
    deltaSec++;
  }
}
```

Note that this is *not* a method but an initializer block which will run at object creation time. I guess this it not intended.

Comment: So, if I were to set public Point getLocation(int xPos, int yPos), would this not be the same as your Point(x,y)? My apologies, still learning how to build constructors properly.

Comment: @Truzen no, `getLocation(x,y)` is just a method taking x and y coordinates and returning a new Point instance. However, that instance has to know the values of x and y. I'll add an example.

Comment: That example does explain converting my point from double to int. Thank you. I've edited 'return new Point' to include '(int)xPos, (int)yPos' and dropped the return point from 'move' and set it to void. However, it's still producing points of 'x=0,y=0'. Hmm....

Comment: @Truzen did you update your code entirely? `getLocation()` seems to still contain `return new Point();`

Comment: @Truzen btw, you should debug your code, e.g. by using the debugger provided by your IDE. That way you can step through every line and see what is done there.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and it didn't flag any lines (at least that I was aware of) for debugging. I do think that my usage and placement of the ArrayList is off and is the key to why I'm outputting 0,0. I'll upload my updated code tomorrow when I get back to my workstation. Thanks for your input so far.

Comment: @Truzen you'd have to start the debugger and set the break points yourself. Eclipse won't automatically debug your code.

Comment: Really? Alright, guess I'll have to learn how to use the debugger. I know that Eclipse flags unused variables and syntax errors; guess I was mistaken in believing that was all of the debugging. Still obviously green at this. Thanks.